# Codeigniter - Session expiration and "remember me" feature

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm building a "Remember Me" feature in Codeigniter, normally I see libraries/projects setting a cookie on the user with a token, this token gets saved in the database and is compared each time the user accesses the website.

In Codeigniter we can set the session expiration time though, this lead me to try a different approach, this is what I did:

- I set the session_expiration in config to 0 (infinite session)
- If the user leaves "Remember me" unchecked, I set a 2 hour time in the session and session destroy on window close.

So my login code looks like this:

```
if (!$this->input->post('remember_me')) {
                $this->session->sess_expiration = 7200;
                $this->session->sess_expire_on_close = TRUE;
            }

            $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
```

And my config file:

```
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
```

I don't see people using this solution on projects, I have tested this out and it seems to work fine though.

SO, for my question, would you say this a safe practice to do? Any security dangers I should know about? Any input on this solution vs cookie+database token would be great.

Answer (score 12):

The simpliest solution that I have found for this problem is to just modify the cookie created by Codeigniter by this way:

```
        $this->session->set_userdata('user', $user); // a cookie has been created
        if($this->input->post('remember_me'))
        {
            $this->load->helper('cookie');
            $cookie = $this->input->cookie('ci_session'); // we get the cookie
            $this->input->set_cookie('ci_session', $cookie, '35580000'); // and add one year to it's expiration
        }
```

Comment: Very useful, thanks. A year is 31557600 seconds though :)

Answer (score 5):

Also this can be done by editing/extending system Session library.

**First:** Set regular session expire time in config file.
**Second:** In user login function add remember me check-

```
    if($remember)
    {
        $data['new_expiration'] = 60*60*24*30;//30 days
        $this->session->sess_expiration = $data['new_expiration'];
    }
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

**Third:** Edit system Session library [I am not sure whether extending Session will work or not]
Go to this line in `sess_read()` method

```
if (($session['last_activity'] + $this->sess_expiration) < $this->now)
```

Before that line add following code

```
if(isset($session['new_expiration'])){
   $this->sess_expiration = $session['new_expiration'];
}
```

This works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say it's not right, but I can tell you my way of doing this:

First I set the session to expires on browser close with a default uptime of 7200.

Then:

1. The login sets session userdata
2. The "remember me" sets a separated  cookie (I store an encrypted hash containing user's email+password+id ie: md5(pass+email+id))

Every time the user loads a page I control if the remember me cookie exist, if exist I create the user session.

The only thing I know is that session, uses an encryption key, a malicious attacker will take time to decrypt, so the less a session key exist the less time attacker has for decrypt the current key.

I always avoid session to not expire, so the Remember me, is always something not good for security I think, but anyway is the user to choose or not if to use that feature ;)