# Codeigniter Setting Remember Me in Sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm trying to implement remember me function to my login form. When user checks the checkbox or not var_dumping the session expiration data is returning 63072000. I couldn't be able to set that and i don't understand why?

How i var_dump:

```
var_dump($this->session->sess_expiration); // returning 63072000
```

form view:

```
<input name="rememberme" value="rememberme" type="checkbox" />
```

login model:

```
$rememberme = $this->input->post('rememberme');
if((!isset($rememberme)) || ($rememberme != "rememberme")){
$this->session->sess_expiration = 10800; // 3 hours
$this->session->sess_expire_on_close = TRUE;
}
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

session config:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Comment: Do you have ci_sessions table in your database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter - Session expiration and "remember me" feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550213/codeigniter-session-expiration-and-remember-me-feature)

Comment: @hyde Doesn't look like a duplicate to me. Both questions relate to the same feature, but that is all.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [forums](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/157027/) at EllisLabs, the session data is set from the `config/config.php` file when the Session Class is initially loaded (which I imagine you are either auto-loading or manually loading before this code in the model), and can't be changed afterwards.

Further down the thread however, it is suggested that you can change the session data. What you might try doing is forcing an update to the session data after setting the expiration configs, while still within the `if` statement:

```
$rememberme = $this->input->post('rememberme');

if( (!isset($rememberme)) || ($rememberme != "remember me") ) {
    $this->session->sess_expiration = 10800; // 3 hours
    $this->session->sess_expire_on_close = TRUE;

    $this->session->sess_update(); //Force an update to the session data
}
```