# sess_expire_on_close on selected userdata on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-timeout

I need set 'sess_expire_on_close' function on certain session only.
I don't want to edit at config.php to make all session wipe while they close the browser.

I need something like...
in my config file:

```
    $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
```

and when I need create a session,does CI have any method like

```
$this->session->set_userdata('temporary','sample data',TRUE);
```

I've been reading this question also , does we have any more solid or CI based's function answer? Instead of writting our own like the link.

[Codeigniter - Session expiration and "remember me" feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550213/codeigniter-session-expiration-and-remember-me-feature)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to set `$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;` on run time.

```
if(!$remeber)
{
   $this->session->sess_expire_on_close = TRUE;
}
else
{
   $this->session->sess_expiration = 60*60*24*31;
   $this->session->sess_expire_on_close = FALSE;
}
```

Here is a great read for this http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/157027/

Comment: I run the code on my controller, but seesm like when i close and reopen back my browser, the session 'status' still remaining.
`public function test(){`
`$this->config->item('sess_expire_on_close', TRUE);`
`$this->session->set_userdata('status', 'testing123');`
`}`

Comment: try `echo $this->config->item('sess_expire_on_close');` to see what was set, and then try to it `TRUE`

Comment: I set
`$this->config->set_item('sess_expire_on_close', TRUE);`
`var_dump($this->config->item('sess_expire_on_close'));`
the result is `bool(true)`
But when i close and reopen back, the userdata stil remain... : ( !